# maven jboss-as:start A required class was missing ... org/sonaty.../ArtifactResolutionException

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I am attempting to start a jboss-as server using the mvn jboss-as:start command and simply put it won't run.

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:start (default-cli) on project thenaglecode: Execution default-cli of goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:start failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:start: org/sonatype/aether/resolution/ArtifactResolutionException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/jxnagl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/as/plugins/jboss-as-maven-plugin/7.4.Final/jboss-as-maven-plugin-7.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/jxnagl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
...
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/jxnagl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/jxnagl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.10/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

This link: '[[Help 1](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound)]' from the above error log at the bottom of the trace shows that this issue is very new, not more than a day old.

the page however is not very useful to me, maybe because i am new to maven so please be nice to me, i.e. i can't figure out what dependency is failing.

Here is my **pom.xml** for your perusal, forgive the overkill on properties, i'm going to revert this way of doing things soon.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>thenaglecode</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0.Pre-Alpha</version>
    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>algorithms</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>testing</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- the nagle code properties -->
        <thenaglecode.java.compiler.version>1.7</thenaglecode.java.compiler.version>
        <thenaglecode.java.home>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25</thenaglecode.java.home>
        <thenaglecode.version>1.0.0.Pre-Alpha</thenaglecode.version>

        <!-- third party library versions format: "libraries.version.<groupid>.<artifactid>" -->
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.jboss-javaee-6.0>3.0.2.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.jboss-javaee-6.0>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.jboss-javaee-all-6.0>3.0.2.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.jboss-javaee-all-6.0>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.as.jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote>7.2.0.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.as.jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.arqullian.protocol.arquillian-protocol-servlet>1.1.0.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.arqullian.protocol.arquillian-protocol-servlet>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.weld.weld-api>2.0.Final</libraries.version.org.jboss.weld.weld-api>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.arquillian.container.arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1>1.0.0.CR4
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.arquillian.container.arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl.jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec>1.0.3.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl.jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec>
        <libraries.version.org.jboss.arquillian.arquillian-bom>1.1.1.Final
        </libraries.version.org.jboss.arquillian.arquillian-bom>
        <libraries.version.xalan.xalan>2.7.1</libraries.version.xalan.xalan>
        <libraries.version.joda-time.joda-time>2.2</libraries.version.joda-time.joda-time>
        <libraries.version.junit.junit>4.11</libraries.version.junit.junit>
        <libraries.version.org.apache.commons.commons-lang3>3.1</libraries.version.org.apache.commons.commons-lang3>
        <libraries.version.commons-collections.commons-collections>3.2.1</libraries.version.commons-collections.commons-collections>
        <libraries.version.commons-io.commons-io>2.4</libraries.version.commons-io.commons-io>

        <!-- plugins format: "plugins.version.<groupid>.<artifactid>" -->
        <plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin>7.4.Final</plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin>
        <plugins.version.org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin>3.1</plugins.version.org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin>
        <plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin>7.4.Final</plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>


        <dependencies>
            <!-- thenaglecode projects -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                <version>${thenaglecode.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
                <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                <version>${thenaglecode.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
                <artifactId>algorithms</artifactId>
                <version>${thenaglecode.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- third party libraries -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.org.jboss.arquillian.arquillian-bom}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.jboss-javaee-all-6.0}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.org.apache.commons.commons-lang3}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.commons-collections.commons-collections}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.commons-io.commons-io}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.junit.junit}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl.jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.xalan.xalan}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>${libraries.version.joda-time.joda-time}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugins.version.org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${thenaglecode.java.compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${thenaglecode.java.compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <javaHome>${thenaglecode.java.home}</javaHome>
                    <execute-commands/>
                    <executeCommands/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Maven 3.1 they switched to using eclipse aether. The jboss-as-maven-plugin uses Sonatype aether as that us what Maven 3.0.x uses. The two versions are not compatible meaning it would require two different plugins would be required. One for Maven 3.1 and one for Maven 3.0.x.

One note is, as you've seen, this only affects the run and start goals. There is no workaround for it. You have to use Maven 3.0.x until a release of the jboss-as-maven-plugin is released that will support eclipse aether.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand [this bug report](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound) : `jboss-as-maven-plugin` have 2 [dependencies](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/plugins.html) on *incompatible* maven plugin (dependency-plugin and enforcer-plugin).

As a workaround, I would try the following : [override incompatible dependencies](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/) with newer versions known to be compatible ([listed here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound)). To do so : change your pom.xml and add the following dependencies for `jboss-as-maven-plugin` (i.e. NOT your project dependencies)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugins.version.org.jboss.as.plugins.jboss-as-maven-plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <javaHome>${thenaglecode.java.home}</javaHome>
                <execute-commands/>
                <executeCommands/>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version> <!--override 2.6-->
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version> <!--override 1.2-->
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Or stay on maven 3.0.x until new version of maven plugin is released with support for maven 3.1

Comment: I have added these dependencies and run it again only to receive the same error. i suppose i'll just have to revert back to maven 3.0.x :(

Comment: Just FYI, this was fixed in newer version of the jboss-as-maven-plugin.  I just upgraded to 7.7.Final and it works just fine with Maven 3.2.5,